# C# Stream.BeginSend

Tags: c#, socket, async

Como podem ver no link abaixo, o método StreamReceiver utiliza o método BeginRead para ler de forma assíncrona, já no método SendData não é utilizado escrita assíncrona, qual a logica de ler de forma assíncrona e escrever de forma síncrona?

Para obter uma boa performance, sendo que o fluxo de dados de leitura e escriva seria praticamente equivalente, deveria ser utilizado BeginSend para escrever também de forma assíncrona?

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Simple_TCP/IP_Server_Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende do tamanho do buffer. Você lê ou escreve de forma assíncrona quando quer aproveitar os ciclos de CPU disponíveis enquanto você aguarda a informação ser transferida pela rede.

No teu exemplo, faria sentido se escrever é pouca coisa e ler é uma tonelada de coisas. De forma que entre a resposta do callback do BeginRead é gigante.

Agora, se ambos são buffers grandes, não faz sentido da forma como está implementado.

No meu blog (http://ericlemes.com) tem algumas coisas sobre I/O assíncrono que podem te ajudar a entender a diferença.

Comment: Ao invés de apontar para o teu Blog, cole o conteúdo do arquivo aqui. Pois o link para o teu Blog pode ficar indisponível com o passar do tempo. Obrigado pela vontade de ajudar, e espero que você não esteja levando para o lado pessoal, mas é assim que o SOpt funciona(Até aonde eu pude entender)!

Comment: Marciano, sem essa de lado pessoal :-). Entendo a política. Mas acho que o inverso é verdadeiro. Se eu for colar o conteúdo que tem e toda a implementação de um socket server aqui, ou trabalhos mais detalhados existentes na internet, ficará ilegível. O mesmo quando alguém referencia uma documentação do msdn. Devemos colar todo o original? Em contrapartida, entendo que a pergunta foi respondida.